# Getting stuck at loading screen on my company's google big query page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

[image]

Everything on the left is greyed out as well.

Any help would be appreciated

Tried searching online but as I am a complete big query novice (cloud computing novice in general) I am not sure what could be the cause of the problem. I have reached out to the admin and they say they have given me the necessary privileges.

Comment: which browser are you using? google chrome? is it up to date?